# Can't delete last character from string stored in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm updating my string values with firebase in real-time. For example, when I type `Google` in my `Title` input box, firebase stores it as such:

[image: Firebase Screenshot of how string is stored]

Now, when I try to update the value of the input by deleting all of the characters in the input field, all of the characters delete but the first character `G`

It seems as though firebase won't let me delete all of the characters and then let me store and empty string. Any ideas why?

```js
// set title
  useEffect(() => {
    if (linkTitleEdit) {
      db.collection("users").doc(user?.uid).collection("links").doc(id).update({
        linkTitle: linkTitleEdit,
      });
    }
  }, [linkTitleEdit]);
```

Here is my input that renders:

```js
<div className="link__title">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder={
                    linkTitle == "Enter Title" ? linkTitle : "Enter Title"
                  }
                  onChange={(e) => setLinkTitleEdit(e.target.value)}
                  value={linkTitle == "Enter Title" ? linkTitleEdit : linkTitle}
                />
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is behind by one change so when are are deleting it is showing the "G" because it was the last character you deleted.  Rather than using useEffect and linkTitleEdit as a dependancy try updating firestore directly onChange in your input.  Remove the use effect code and try using this below:

```
    <div className="link__title">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder={
                        linkTitle == "Enter Title" ? linkTitle : "Enter Title"
                      }
                      onChange={(e) => 

 db.collection("users").doc(user?.uid).collection("links").doc(id).update({
        linkTitle: e.target.value,
      });
}
                      value={linkTitle == "Enter Title" ? linkTitleEdit : linkTitle}
                    />
                  </div>
```

I would have to see more context to know for sure but i suspect this will fix it.

Comment: Hi David! This makes so much sense! However, I think the formating is a bit off because I can't get the function to run. I remove ```setLinkTitleEdit(e.target.value)``` and it worked. Thanks so much man!